# Find azure resource by multiple tags?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I have a multiple machines in Azure ResourceManager.
those machine are tagged with version of application that is running on them.

How do find the machines by multiple tags?

My tags on VMS are for example:
environment: development / production
version: 1.0.1/1.2/1.5

I want to be able to fin all production virtual machines with specific tags

*environment:production and version:1.0*

Here is my powershell I tried:

**Find-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ environment="production"; version = "1.5"}**

the problem with this is, it respect only first tag, and therefore I get all virtual machines that are with the tag, but does not filter it on the version

Comment: works for me, try removing the trailing `)`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, since this doesnt work for you but works for me only real conclusión we can draw from this: update your Azure Powershell modules.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, but did not work about an hour ago. I am confused.